# Correct usage of typedef and REGISTER in boost geometry

Tags: c++, boost-geometry

Some of the boost geometry examples use typedef and some use various REGISTER macros.  I am confused how these should be combined.

This code fails to compile

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;
using namespace std;

class cxy
{
public:
    double x;
    double y;
    cxy( double X, double Y )
        : x( X )
        , y( Y )
    {

    }
};

BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D( cxy, double, bg::cs::cartesian, x, y )
typedef bg::model::point<double, 2, bg::cs::cartesian> point_t;
typedef bg::model::segment<point_t> segment_t;

int main()
{
    cxy a(0,0);
    cxy b(1,1);
    cxy c(1,0);
    cxy d(0,1) ;
    segment_t ab( a, b );
    segment_t cd( c, d );
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler output

```
-------------- Build: Debug in bgintersect (compiler: gcc_v83)---------------

g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g -IC:\Users\James\code\boost\boost_1_72_0 -c C:\Users\James\code\bgintersect\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
g++.exe  -o \bin\bgintersect.exe obj\Debug\main.o  -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -static  
C:\Users\James\code\bgintersect\main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
C:\Users\James\code\bgintersect\main.cpp:31:24: error: no matching function for call to 'boost::geometry::model::segment<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >::segment(cxy&, cxy&)'
     segment_t ab( a, b );
                        ^
In file included from C:\Users\James\code\boost\boost_1_72_0/boost/geometry/strategies/intersection_strategies.hpp:18,
                 from C:\Users\James\code\boost\boost_1_72_0/boost/geometry/strategies/strategies.hpp:39,
                 from C:\Users\James\code\boost\boost_1_72_0/boost/geometry/geometry.hpp:49,
                 from C:\Users\James\code\boost\boost_1_72_0/boost/geometry.hpp:17,
                 from C:\Users\James\code\bgintersect\main.cpp:2:
C:\Users\James\code\boost\boost_1_72_0/boost/geometry/geometries/segment.hpp:64:12: note: candidate: 'boost::geometry::model::segment<Point>::segment(const Point&, const Point&) [with Point = boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>]'
     inline segment(Point const& p1, Point const& p2)
            ^~~~~~~
C:\Users\James\code\boost\boost_1_72_0/boost/geometry/geometries/segment.hpp:64:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'cxy' to 'const boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>&'
C:\Users\James\code\boost\boost_1_72_0/boost/geometry/geometries/segment.hpp:54:5: note: candidate: 'constexpr boost::geometry::model::segment<Point>::segment() [with Point = boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>]'
     segment() = default;
     ^~~~~~~
C:\Users\James\code\boost\boost_1_72_0/boost/geometry/geometries/segment.hpp:54:5: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
C:\Users\James\code\boost\boost_1_72_0/boost/geometry/geometries/segment.hpp:46:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr boost::geometry::model::segment<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >::segment(const boost::geometry::model::segment<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >&)'
 class segment : public std::pair<Point, Point>
       ^~~~~~~
C:\Users\James\code\boost\boost_1_72_0/boost/geometry/geometries/segment.hpp:46:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
C:\Users\James\code\boost\boost_1_72_0/boost/geometry/geometries/segment.hpp:46:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr boost::geometry::model::segment<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >::segment(boost::geometry::model::segment<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >&&)'
C:\Users\James\code\boost\boost_1_72_0/boost/geometry/geometries/segment.hpp:46:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
C:\Users\James\code\bgintersect\main.cpp:32:24: error: no matching function for call to 'boost::geometry::model::segment<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >::segment(cxy&, cxy&)'
     segment_t cd( c, d );
                        ^
In file included from C:\Users\James\code\boost\boost_1_72_0/boost/geometry/strategies/intersection_strategies.hpp:18,
                 from C:\Users\James\code\boost\boost_1_72_0/boost/geometry/strategies/strategies.hpp:39,
                 from C:\Users\James\code\boost\boost_1_72_0/boost/geometry/geometry.hpp:49,
                 from C:\Users\James\code\boost\boost_1_72_0/boost/geometry.hpp:17,
                 from C:\Users\James\code\bgintersect\main.cpp:2:
C:\Users\James\code\boost\boost_1_72_0/boost/geometry/geometries/segment.hpp:64:12: note: candidate: 'boost::geometry::model::segment<Point>::segment(const Point&, const Point&) [with Point = boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>]'
     inline segment(Point const& p1, Point const& p2)
            ^~~~~~~
C:\Users\James\code\boost\boost_1_72_0/boost/geometry/geometries/segment.hpp:64:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'cxy' to 'const boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>&'
C:\Users\James\code\boost\boost_1_72_0/boost/geometry/geometries/segment.hpp:54:5: note: candidate: 'constexpr boost::geometry::model::segment<Point>::segment() [with Point = boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>]'
     segment() = default;
     ^~~~~~~
C:\Users\James\code\boost\boost_1_72_0/boost/geometry/geometries/segment.hpp:54:5: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
C:\Users\James\code\boost\boost_1_72_0/boost/geometry/geometries/segment.hpp:46:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr boost::geometry::model::segment<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >::segment(const boost::geometry::model::segment<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >&)'
 class segment : public std::pair<Point, Point>
       ^~~~~~~
C:\Users\James\code\boost\boost_1_72_0/boost/geometry/geometries/segment.hpp:46:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
C:\Users\James\code\boost\boost_1_72_0/boost/geometry/geometries/segment.hpp:46:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr boost::geometry::model::segment<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >::segment(boost::geometry::model::segment<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >&&)'
C:\Users\James\code\boost\boost_1_72_0/boost/geometry/geometries/segment.hpp:46:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 3 second(s))
2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 3 second(s))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You register a point type, not "the" point type.

I.e. when you register it, you probably wanted to start using it *as /your/ point type*. Change `point_t` accordingly:

```
using point_t = cxy;
```

Or, indeed, just use `cxy` directly

```
typedef bg::model::segment<cxy> segment_t;
```

---

Also, add constructabiliity, prefer template aliases etc:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f536cfa36498eca2)**

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;

struct cxy {
    double x, y;
    cxy(double x = 0, double y = 0) : x(x), y(y) {}
};

BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D(cxy, double, bg::cs::cartesian, x, y)
using segment_t = bg::model::segment<cxy>;

int main() {
    cxy a{0, 0},
        b{1, 1},
        c{1, 0},
        d{0, 1};
    segment_t ab(a, b);
    segment_t cd(c, d);
}
```

Comment: The trick is to provide a default constructor for the point class!